# Can I select all elements whose attribute names (not values) start with a certain string?

Tags: javascript, css

Say that I have this markup excerpt:

```
<p onblur="...">text 1</p>
<p class="myclass">text 2</p>
<p onfocus="...">text 3</p>
```

Is there a CSS selector that I could use to get the first and last elements (but not the middle) using the fact that they both have attributes that start with 'on'?  I'm looking for a general solution rather than something for this particular case (since, of course, the intended outcome could be achieved in much more straightforward ways for this particular example).

A Javascript-based solution would work fine for me too (though I'm hoping to avoid the brute force examine-every-element approach).  That's actually what I'm looking for (a selector that can be used with jQuery or a similar library).

Comment: LOL that was a nice edit, I thought the `pre` with encoded html was the OP's code.

Comment: I think you'd be better off finding a completely different coding strategy. Binding event handlers via "onfoo" attributes is pretty limiting, and it commingles code and markup. If you used JavaScript to discover elements and bind handlers, you could mark them with a class to indicate that fact.

Comment: I think it is a ugly design to select over the attribute names. Maybe you can add a better selector.

Comment: does `[onabort],[onbeforecopy],[onbeforecut],[onbeforepaste],[onblur],[onchange],[onclick],[oncontextmenu],[oncopy],[oncut],[ondblclick],[ondrag],[ondragend],[ondragenter],[ondragleave],[ondragover],[ondragstart],[ondrop],[onerror],[onfocus],[oninput],[oninvalid],[onkeydown],[onkeypress],[onkeyup],[onload],[onmousedown],[onmousemove],[onmouseout],[onmouseover],[onmouseup],[onmousewheel],[onpaste],[onreset],[onscroll],[onsearch],[onselect],[onselectstart],[onsubmit]
` do it?

Comment: @Esailija I think you want commas between those, no?

Comment: @Esailija  Sweet, I believe that would do the trick, thanks!

Comment: @Pointy - I totally agree, but I don't control the markup, and it also has to work for any arbitrary markup (especially markup like the above) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointy pointed out, this isn't the recommended way of going around things. Simply use a class to group elements that you want to target at once.

However, you can target most event handlers with this:

```
[onabort],[onbeforecopy],[onbeforecut],[onbeforepaste],[onblur],[onchange],[onclick],[oncontextmenu],[oncopy],[oncut],[ondblclick],[ondrag],[ondragend],[ondragenter],[ondragleave],[ondragover],[ondragstart],[ondrop],[onerror],[onfocus],[oninput],[oninvalid],[onkeydown],[onkeypress],[onkeyup],[onload],[onmousedown],[onmousemove],[onmouseout],[onmouseover],[onmouseup],[onmousewheel],[onpaste],[onreset],[onscroll],[onsearch],[onselect],[onselectstart],[onsubmit] {
  color: #BADBAD;   
}
```

See demo http://jsfiddle.net/uwXgt/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS selector to choose based on element attributes:

```
p[onfocus] { color:blue; }
p[class=myclass] { color:red; }
```

But there's no way in CSS to choose based on the first part of the attributes name.