# Python BeautifulSoup select all elements whose attribute starts with

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to select all elements who has at least one attribute that starts with "responsive-"

```
<div reponsive-devices="desktop"></div> #Select this
<ul responsive-os="android"></ul> # Select this
<div class="responsive-"></div> # DON'T select this
```

I already tried this: [Can I select all elements whose attribute names (not values) start with a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710541/can-i-select-all-elements-whose-attribute-names-not-values-start-with-a-certai) but it couldn't help me.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not straightforward but you can iterate over the tags and check if any of the attribute is starting with `responsive`.

See below code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<div responsive-devices="desktop"></div>
<ul responsive-os="android"></ul>
<div class="responsive-"></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data))

responsive_tag_list = soup.findAll(
                lambda tag:
                any([i.startswith('responsive-') for i in tag.attrs])
                )

print(responsive_tag_list)
```

Output:

```
[<div responsive-devices="desktop"></div>, <ul responsive-os="android"></ul>]
```